# Mosfet switching

Tags: mosfet, switching

I'm implementing mosfet switching circuitry using the P channel enchancement mode mosfet DMP2305U.Where Vs = 3V and Vg is using as control voltage and toggleing between 0 and 3V . When Vg is zero volts , I'm getting output at Vd as high , when Vg is 3Volts I'm getting output at Vd as low as desired functionality, but i'm not getting the sufficient current through the mosfet . It seems like Vth of this mosfet is -0.9V and as a ground rule , Vgs should be greater than Vth to supply the max current , but  here in my case Vgs is -3V (When the mosfet is on Vg=0v and  Vs=3) .Here, do we need to consider the signs ?(negative , positive) of Vgs and Vth ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL1NN2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Drain current is dependent on load. What load do you have on the drain to 0 volts? Note that R1 is not connected in the right place to act as a load.

Answer (score 1):

> when Vg is 3Volts I'm getting output at Vd as low as desired functionality, but i'm not getting the sufficient current through the mosfet .

When you pull the gate to 3 V, you are putting the MOSFET in cut-off mode. You should expect approximately 0 current between source and drain. Figure 10 in the datasheet shows the typical leakage current in cut-off, and it is measured in nanoamps.

> It seems like Vth of this mosfet is -0.9V and as a ground rule , Vgs should be greater than Vth to supply the max current ,

For a p-channel MOSFET like this one, \$V_{gs}\$ should be less than \$V_{th}\$ to enter triode or saturation operation, not greater than \$V_{th}\$.

> do we need to consider the signs ?(negative , positive) of Vgs and Vth ?

Yes, you need \$V_{gs} < V_{th}\$ to form a channel, and \$V_{th}\$ will be less than 0 for an enhancement mode p-channel MOSFET.